# Disable Azure Blob direct download

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, blob

Is it possible to restrict/disable Azure Blobs direct download (when you just enter link in the browser) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you provide access to blob either through public or even with SAS, you can not blob them to DOWNLOAD the blob if they want.

If you will provide a link which includes a blob from public container as below, then any one can download the blob as long as they know the URL:

```
http[s]://your_azure_storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/public_container/blob_name
```

However if you provide a link to your blog using [SAS signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx) API then you can restrict the access to blob to restricted users, however they still can download the blob once they have access to the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't make the container public and folks won't be able to download the blobs anonymously. If you require some type of ACL, you'll need to create a service that performs the ACL check then returns the stream for the blob to approved users.